# Error with post ID parameters declaration in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

The below is causing an error specifically with Wordpress 6.3. Its mainly with this line:

```php
            $children = get_pages( array( 'child_of' => $post->ID ) );
```

which i updated to:

```php
           $children = get_pages('child_of='.$post->ID);
```

Which doesnt work either, below is the complete code

```php
 $post = get_post();
        //print_r($post);

        if ($post->post_parent == 0) {
            
            $children = get_pages('child_of='.$post->ID);


            if( count( $children ) != 0 ){
                echo '<h2 class="sidebar-title"><a href="' . get_permalink( $post->ID) . '">' . $post->post_title . '</a></h2>';
                $query->set( 'post_parent', $post->ID );
            } else {
                $post = get_post(get_option( 'page_on_front' ));
                echo '<h2 class="sidebar-title"><a href="' . get_permalink( $post->ID) . '">' . $post->post_title . '</a></h2>';
                $query->set( 'post_parent', 0 );
                $query->set( 'post__not_in', array($post->ID) );
            }
        }
```